# Cкрыть категорию товаров для незарегистрированных пользователей woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Мне нужно скрыть категорию 18+ на сайте для незарегистрированных клиентов. В гугл искал, находит только платные плагины, бесплатных решений я не нашел. Что можно сделать в такой ситуации?

```
function my_product_query( $q ) {
$is_logged_in = is_user_logged_in();
$cat = 'categorie-1';

if ( !$is_logged_in ) {
    $q->set( 'tax_query',
        array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'sex',
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_product_query', 10, 1 );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Написать проверку через is_user_logged_in(). Эта функция возвращает true если пользователь авторизован и false если нет.

Comment: Написал код, но как вывести сообщение о том, что нужно авторизоваться? (код в закрепил в вопросе)